# Calculate minimum distance of point in image mask to a set of points

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, pixel, opencv3.0

I have an image mask (differenceM) like this:
[image]

For every single white pixel (pixel value != 0), I want to calculate the minimum distance from that pixel to a set of points. The set of points are points on the external contour which will be stored as a numpy array of [x_val y_val]. I was thinking of doing this:

```
...
def calcMinDist(dilPoints):
    ...

#returns 2d array (same shape as image)
def allMinDistDil(dilMask):
    dilPoints = getPoints(dilMask)
    ...
    return arrayOfMinValues

#more code here

blkImg = np.zeros(maskImage.shape,dtype=np.uint8)
blkImg.fill(0) 

img_out = np.where(differenceM,allMinDistDil(dilatedMask),blkImg)

....
```

But the problem with this is, in order to calculate minimum distance from a pixel point to a set of points (obtained from getPoints function), I'll need to pass in the pixel point (index?) as well. But (if my understanding is correct,) with this where function, it only checks for true and false values in the first parameter...So the way I wrote the np.where() function won't work.

I've considered using nested for loops for this problem but I'm trying to avoid using for loops because I have a lot of images to process.

May I ask for suggestions to solve this? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: hi Reine, having trouble understanding in part because you have an indentation error

Comment: Hi @kevinkayaks, may I ask which part(s)? Also, may I ask where's the indentation error? Maybe I'll edit the code so its clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the np.where() function to find the specific pixels that are not zero, I applied:

```
diffMaskNewArray = np.transpose(np.nonzero(binaryThreshMask))
```

to get the points where the values are not zeros. With this array of points, I iterated through each point in this array and compared it with the array of boundary points of the masks and used:

```
shortestDistDil = np.amin(distance.cdist(a, b, 'euclidean'))
```

to find the min distance between the point and the set of boundary points.

Answer (score 1):

(not enough rep to comment) As for distance you probably want [scipy.spatial.distance.cdist( X, Y )](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html) . You can calculate a minimum distance with as simple as:

```
from scipy.spatial import distance

def min_distance(points, set_of_points):
    return distance.cdist(np.atleast_1d(point), set_of_points).min()
```

As for np.where can you provide a bit more on your data structure? Most of the times a simple boolean mask will do the job...

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @Mstaino! But actually I was more confused about the np.where() part to work more than the cdist part. Maybe I should phrase my question more clearly next time.

Comment: No problem, maybe adding a data sample is useful as image formats in numpy can vary. Glad you found a solution. Cheers